# Display partial view in colorbox modal?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have an ajax call which returns a partial view which I want to dump into a colorbox modal.  I have tried all sorts of different ways but it just opens up with something like "Content cannot be displayed".  I have checked the data being returned and it is definitely the partial view so I don't know why it's failing to display it.  I also tried the jQuery plugin simple modal which I was able to use very easily to display the same partial view by using $.modal(data).  When I try the different ways below I get the error message.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'Controller/ControllerAction',
  success: function(data) {
  $(data).colorbox();

  }
});

 $.ajax({
  url: 'Controller/ControllerAction',
  success: function(data) {
  $.colorbox(data);

  }
});

 $.ajax({
  url: 'Controller/ControllerAction',
  success: function(data) {
  $.colorbox({html: data });

  }
});
```

Any ideas would be greatly welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$.colorbox({
    href: 'Controller/ControllerAction'
});
```